# Paste entire column using as target a single cell which is not in the first row

Tags: vba, excel

Is it really impossible to paste an entire column of data if the cells selected are **not in the first row**?

I always get the error below if I try it

*The information cannot be pasted because the Copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape...*

Any form of help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: if the cells are not of the same size(like mergecells or resized rows...) , you can always paste only the values using pastespecial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually impossible, either in VBA or directly. And it would not make any sense.

You could select an entire column less the last cell (last row), e.g., `A1:A[last row - 1]`. Copy that range, and paste into, e.g., `B2`. That would work.

As a generalization, you could select `A1:A[last row - n]`. Copy that range, and paste into `B[n+1]`.

This will probably perform the action you mean, and you could easily write code for that.

Answer (score 0):

For copy choose a cell and End key then Shift + Down key to select a contigous column.

Then to paste choose a single cell.

You can record this with Macro Recorder (Alt + T, M, R).